# JavaFX clearRect clears pixels outside the given region

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, paint

I have the following code to draw squares on canvas and overwrite original pixels if the fill color is transparent.

```java
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.clearRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
gc.fillRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
```

However, the result of drawing 9 squares is like this:

[image: malfunction result]

Rather than the following which I expect

[image: expected result]

It looks like clearRect affects an extra row on the top and an extra column on the left than drawRect. If I use these code then it works fine.

```java
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.clearRect(x * size + 1, y * size + 1, size - 1, size - 1);
gc.fillRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
```

I cannot find information from the documentation to justify my correction. Why the original code does not work as expected but the correction works?