# JavaFX GraphicsContext.clearRect(..) behavior

Tags: java, javafx

I have a question about understanding the behavior of clearRect() in JavaFX, using JavaFX 18.0.2 & OpenJDK 17.0.9+9:

In the following example, clearRect() doest not clear the given 10x10px area as expected.Output is:

**Try with Clear:**

```
Color:0xffffffff : 100

Color:0x0000ffff : 22379

Color:0x4040ffff : 1

Color:0x8080ffff : 20

**Try with fill**

Color:0xffffffff : 100

Color:0x0000ffff : 22400
```

I would expect `clearRect` having the same output as with `fillRect()`. But instead, with `clearRect()` some other colors appear.

### EDIT

I disabled `hidpi` with `-Dprism.allowhidpi=false`. 0x4040ffff and 0x8080ffff seem to came from antialising. Now, with `hidpi=false`, the cleared `rect` is not 10x10px but 11x11:

**Try with Clear**

```
Color:0xffffffff : 121

Color:0x0000ffff : 22379
```

**Try with Fill**

```
Color:0xffffffff > 100

Color:0x0000ffff > 22400
```

Does anyone know whats happening?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClearRectTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(150, 150);
        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        
        System.out.println("\nTry with Clear\n-");
        gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
        gc.clearRect(30, 30, 10, 10);
        
        {
            Map<Color, Integer> colorMap = countColors(canvas);
            for (Color c : colorMap.keySet()) {
                System.out.println("Color:" + c + " : " + colorMap.get(c));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nTry with fill\n-");
        
        gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);

        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        gc.fillRect(30, 30, 10, 10);

        {
            Map<Color, Integer> colorMap = countColors(canvas);
            for (Color c : colorMap.keySet()) {
                System.out.println("Color:" + c + " : " + colorMap.get(c));
            }
        }
    }

    public static Map<Color, Integer> countColors(Canvas canvas) {
        WritableImage fxImage = canvas.snapshot(null, null);
        Map<Color, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        PixelReader pixelReader = fxImage.getPixelReader();
        for (int y = 0; y < fxImage.getHeight(); ++y){
            for (int x = 0; x < fxImage.getWidth(); ++x) {
                Color c = pixelReader.getColor(x, y);
                Integer i = map.get(c);
                map.put(c, i == null ? 1 : i + 1);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The [API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) says, "[1] Only the Transform, Clip, and Effect apply to `clearRect()`."

Comment: The javadoc says “Clears a portion of the canvas with a transparent color value.”  So I would expect your current color to be ignored.  And I would expect to see the colors of whatever object is underneath the Canvas.

Comment: This is correct. Changing the background color to red leaves a red square at the cleared area. But the size of this area of 11x11px is still strange to me.

Comment: is it clearing 11x11 pixels simply because it indexes starting at 0? I feel like I should know this...

Comment: @Christoph: try other values of `BlendMode` to see the effect; examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70089503/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I tried every `BlendMode`. Except SRC_OVER, all others dont have any effect. `SRC_OVER` clears 11x11 instead of 10x10. I found a guy with the same problem but no solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713996/javafx-clearrect-clears-pixels-outside-the-given-region)

Comment: A similar effect is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415269/230513): You can't draw with clear. Different abstraction; same target.

Comment: seems like CSS style controls what the transparent color is, and it seems to be white by default, not actually the #0000000 described in the javadoc. but if you dont have a scene, then styles seem not to be applied correctly like manual says.